# How does pointer declaration and definition work for pointers?

Tags: c, pointers

For the following code spinet:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int x = 12345678;
    char *a = x;

    printf("%d\n", x);

    printf("%d\n %d\n %d\n %d\n", a[0], a[1], a[2], a[3]);

    return 0;
}
```

output for GNU GCC v7.1.1:
    timeout: the monitored command dumped core
    sh: line 1: 11792 Segmentation fault      timeout 10s main

Note that following works:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int x = 12345678;
    char *a;
    *a = x;

    printf("%d\n", x);

    printf("%d\n %d\n %d\n %d\n", a[0], a[1], a[2], a[3]);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @Vishal gupta The both programs have undefined behavior.

Comment: You should check concepts of pointer to reference and pointing to a reference.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Neither of these is correct.

In both cases, you are assigning an integer value to a pointer.  That value is then treated as a valid memory location and dereferenced.  But it is not a valid memory location, so you invoke [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

In the first case, UB manifests as a crash, and in the second case it manifests as appearing to work properly.

What you need to do is assign the *address* of `x` to `a`.  Then you can read the bytes that make up the `int`.

```
char *a = (char *)&x;
```